# Any source for this quote or this concept?

Tags: torah-study, amen

I am looking to see if anybody knows a possible source for the concept of a word of Torah being worth 1,000 "yehei shmei rabbahs", based on the story below, taken from https://www.etzahaim.org/rabbi-message/2018/9/26/the-alter-of-kelm-rabbi-simcha-zissel-ziv.

"Amazing Statement by the Alter of Kelm, Rabbi Simcha Zissel Ziv on the Value of Talmud Torah.

Hashem created this world so that mankind should come to recognize Him and proclaim: baruch hu ubarach ubaruch shemo. “It was worth creating the entire universe, sustaining and fueling it for six thousand years... all so that... in the course of its existence - there will be at least one person who will say baruch hu u’baru’ch shemo at least once in their lifetime.  For this alone, the world's purpose has already been fulfilled. And yet…

1,000 of these baruch hu ubaruch shemos do not measure up the value of one amen!

1,000 amens will not measure up to the value of one amen yehe shmeh rabbah!

1,000 Amen yehe shmeh rabbahs will not add up to the value of one word of Torah!"

Comment: I assume he meant no amount of Amen yehe etc. will add up to one word of Torah because Torah is qualitatively superior to Tefillah. See Nefesh Hachayim sha'ar daled.

Comment: So you're asking whether anyone disagrees with him? He said a thousand יהא שמה רבא's _don't_ equal a word of Torah, and you want to know if anyone says they _do_?